# Django Social Login: 'AsgiRequest' object has no attribute 'session'

Tags: python, django

Got an error when trying social-app-django (2.1.0), the error thrown was:

> 'AsgiRequest' object has no attribute 'session'

- Running with channels 1.1.8, Django 2.0.3, asgi-redis 1.2.0, python 3.6
- Running via python manage.py runserver (development environment) not uwgsi or nginx.

The occurs when trying to access /social/login/google-oauth2/ (authenticating with google account).

I have read about changing **MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES** to **MIDDLEWARE** but we have been using Django >=1.9 for a while so it has already been changed.

The traceback looks as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35,in inner
>       response = get_response(request)
>
> File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 243, in process_exception_by_middleware
>       return super(AsgiHandler, self).process_exception_by_middleware(exception, request)
>
> File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
>       response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/social_django/utils.py", line 38, in wrapper
>       request.social_strategy = load_strategy(request)
>
> File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/social_django/utils.py", line 23, in load_strategy
>       return get_strategy(STRATEGY, STORAGE, request)
>
> File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/social_core/utils.py", line 279, in get_strategy
>       return Strategy(Storage, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/social_django/strategy.py", line 39, in **init**
>       self.session = request.session if request else {}
>   AttributeError: 'AsgiRequest' object has no attribute 'session'

Middleware is the following (added because other **WsgiRequest has no attribute session** have been related with middleware):

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",

    "social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware",

    "django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with middleware. I upgraded from Django>=1.9 to 2.0.3. SessionAuthenticationMiddleware was removed. When debugging middleware I found this:

> ImportError: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class

The solution was to removed it. The reason why didn't it logged it out before it is unknown.

You can read more about this here:

[SessionAuthenticationMiddleware removed release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#miscellaneous)